# Angular compile error when going to version 1.3.0-beta.12

Tags: angularjs

When I updated to 1.3.0-beta.12, and I fire up my application, I get:

> Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.12/$compile/multidir?p0=ngController…v%20class%3D%22off-canvas-wrap%22%20ng-controller%3D%22OffCanvasCtrl%22%3E
>   at Error (native)
>   at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.12/angular.min.js:6:457
>   at La (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.12/angular.min.js:63:19)

So far I cannot track down what changed in beta.12 to cause this to happen.
I'm hoping this is an issue someone has run into, that it is a known common issue.

Comment: Why not update to [1.3 stable](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js)? Also, you get much more readable error messages in the non-minified version of angular. Also, those links are clickable ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=ngController%E2%80%A6v%20class%3D%22off-canvas-wrap%22%20ng-controller%3D%22OffCanvasCtrl%22%3E

Comment: I updated to the stable version, any help on what this error means: Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngController, offCanvasWrap] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div class="off-canvas-wrap" ng-controller="OffCanvasCtrl">

Comment: That error happen  when 2 directives are in conflict... so in this case I guess your OffCanvasWrap is the main problem.. here is the docs that list the possible origin of your problem and the solution.. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is there because you have two directive on same div asking for isolate scope

```
      <div class="off-canvas-wrap" ng-controller="OffCanvasCtrl">
```

what you can do to resolve this issue is move the another directive on a child scope

```
      <div class="off-canvas-wrap"> 
      <div ng-controller="OffCanvasCtrl"> 

      </div>
      </div>
```

you should use the sequence whichever is appropriate as per the implementation of off-canvas-wrap directive.